# Error handling with Scoping Routes using app.use('url','route_file')

Tags: javascript, node.js

1.Can anyone tell me how to allow my error to pass through the app.use('/blogs','blogRoutes') middle ware that scopes my url to a api file?

2.Is the answer something like app.use('/blogs','blogRoutes', next){next(err)}?

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');

//use Mongo Db
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const blogRoutes = require ('./route/blogroutes');
const app = express();




//connect to mongo db
const dBurI = mongo database key
mongoose.connect(dBurI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
.then((result)=> app.listen(3000))
.catch((err)=>console.log(err))

//middleware stack
// allows use of view engine to render  - html files in views foles are suffixed with ejs these are found automatically due to views folder beign recognised
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));                  //access ppblic folder files - css
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));      //url data and passes into object that can be used on req => req.body
app.use(morgan('dev'));




//redirect route
app.get('/',(req, res, next)=>{
  res.redirect('/blogs');
  next(err);
});

app.get('/about',(req, res, next)=>{
    //send file to a browser
    res.render('about', {title: 'About' });
    next(err);
});

//redirect 301
app.get('about-me',(req,res, next)=>{
  res.redirect('./about');
  next(err);
});

//blogroutes
app.use('/blogs','blogRoutes'); //scope all blog urls to blogrouter
    

// middle ware app.use is called immediately if above are not found - error page 404
app.use((err,req,res)=>{
    res.status(404).render('404', {title: '404', error: err });
});
```

Comment: In Express custom error handling function should have 4 arguments instead of 3, so try with `app.use((err, req, res, next) => {})`

Comment: yes thanks, but my main issue with allowing the errors above or in the app.use(url, router_file) to pass through the custom error handler - that allows me to use one page for all errors.

Comment: do I just add, app.use(err,'/blogs','blogRoutes', next)
or
app.use(err,'/blogs','blogRoutes'){next(err);}

Answer (score 0):

1.after reading the express documentation I believe the answer for espress5+ is as follows:

```
//redirect route
app.get('/',(req, res, next)=>{
  res.redirect('/blogs');
  
});

app.get('/about',(req, res, next)=>{
    //send file to a browser
    res.render('about', {title: 'About' });
    
});

//redirect 301
app.get('about-me',(req,res, next)=>{
  res.redirect('./about');
  ;
});

//blogroutes
app.use('/blogs','blogRoutes',(req,res,next)); //scope all blog urls to blogrouter
    

// middle ware app.use is called immediately if above are not found - error page 404
app.use((err,req,res, next)=>{
    res.status(404).render('404', {title: '404', error: err });
});
```

2.read this doucmentations and see if im write if not then I believe I have to do this:

```
//redirect route
app.get('/',(req, res, next)=>{
  res.redirect('/blogs');
  next(err);
  
});

app.get('/about',(req, res, next)=>{
    //send file to a browser
    res.render('about', {title: 'About' });
    next(err);
});

//redirect 301
app.get('about-me',(req,res, next)=>{
  res.redirect('./about');
  next(err);
});

//blogroutes
app.use('/blogs','blogRoutes',(req,res,next)=>{next(err);}); //scope all blog urls to blogrouter
    

// middle ware app.use is called immediately if above are not found - error page 404
app.use((err,req,res, next)=>{
    res.status(404).render('404', {title: '404', error: err });//next would call the express error handler automatically if used here..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the error handling behaviour in Express - 4.17:

1. You do not need to explicitly pass the error to the error handling middleware for synchronized operation. Express will take care of it for you. This can be confirmed by sending a GET request to the `/` route. In this case, your app does not crash.
2. If an error occurs during async operations, you must explicitly pass the error to the next middleware using `next()`. I created two routes to test this behaviour: `/async` and `/async_next`. If you visit the `/async` route, your app should crash because we are not explicitly handling the error. Once you restart your app and navigate to the `/async_next` route, you will notice that it does not crash and that the error is handled by the custom error handling middleware.

For understanding the above points refer to the following code -

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen('3001', () => console.log("listening port - 3001"));

app.get('/async', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Async function');
    setTimeout(() => { throw new Error('Async Err from settimeout') }, 1);
})

app.get('/async_next', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Async function');
    setTimeout(() => {
        next(new Error('Async Err from settimeout'))
    }, 1);
})

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    throw new Error('Random Sync Err');
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Error from custom handler ', err);
    res.send('Error');
});
```

Comment: 1. also you've not answered question fully - but I think you still need to use err argument to make the following error handler to pass messages to a html page...

```
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(404).render('404', {title: 'Error Page', error_message: 'err.message'});
}):
```
2.Unless you are saying the following will work?
```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(404).render('404', {title: 'Error Page', error_message: 'err.message'});
}):
```
3. You need to add a function to he routing middleware.
```
app.use('/blogs','blogRoutes',(req,res,next));
```

Answer (score 0):

1.so this seems right but need testing...

```
//redirect route
app.get('/',(req, res, next)=>{
  res.redirect('/blogs');
});

app.get('/about',(req, res, next)=>{
    //send file to a browser
    res.render('about', {title: 'About' });
});

//redirect 301
app.get('about-me',(req,res,next)=>{
  res.redirect('./about');
});

//blogroutes
app.use('/blogs','blogRoutes',(req,res,next)); //scope all blog urls to blogrouter
    
// middle ware app.use is called immediately if above are not found - error page 404
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(err.status).render('404', {title: 'Error Page', error_message: 'err.message'});
}):
```

2. You error handler needs to look like this even with express 5+

```
function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err)
  }
  res.status(500)
  res.render('error', { error: err })
}
```

3. You need the err argument to reference to the error...